# Windows Store app ComboBox fire event on user change

Tags: events, windows-8, combobox

In my Windows Store (Metro) app, my ComboBoxes fire their selectionChanged() events every time their item sources get updated or their selected value/index gets changed in code. How do I make it so that these events only fire when the user selects a different value? Note - I tried looking for SelectionChangeCommitted, but MSVS claims this event doesn't exist.

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it fixed by adding a flag (a bool) in the page, which is set to true during the loading process. Before it is set, the selectionChanged() methods will return before doing anything.